# Allow user to input unique values

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to get input from the user to select players from an ArrayList. All the players in the ArrayList have a unique ID the user selects 5 - 8 players to start the program but I do not want to allow the user to input the same ID again as it will have a duplicate.
Heres what I m trying to do

```
I still am not getting this I tried this  

     public void SelectAthlete(){
       Data ath = new Data();
         ath.athleteData();
        boolean choice = true;
        int p=0;
        String id;
        int value =0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        do{
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("\tEnter the number of Participants you want to Compete: ");
            p=input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\tYou have Decided to compete with" +" " + p + " " +"Athletes");
            if(p>=5 && p<=8){
                System.out.println("\tEnter the Athlete ID :    ");
                for (int i=0;i<p;i++){
                    value=0;
                    id = input.next();
                    if(id.substring(0,1).equals("R") || id.substring(0,1).equals("P")){ 

                        for(int k=0;i<Data.AthleteData.size();k++)
                        {
                    if(Data.AthleteData.get(k).getID().contains(id))
                        {
                        value++;
                        choice = Data.Inputlist.add(id);
                        }
                    else if (!choice)
                    {
                        value--;
                        System.out.println("Please Enter Unique Value");
                        input.nextLine();
                    }                       

                        for(int j = 0; j<Data.AthleteData.size();j++)
                        {
                            if(id.equals(Data.AthleteData.get(j).getID()))
                            {
                                value++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    if(value!=0)
                    {
                        Data.Inputlist.add(id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Enter a valid ID (in UPPER Case)");
                        input.nextLine();
                        i--;
                    }

                }
                choice = false;

            }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("\n\tHowever You need to have 
       atleast 5 Athletes or atmost 8 Athletes to Start a game.");
      input.nextLine();
      } 
            for (int m=0;m<Data.AthleteData.size();m++){                    
               if (Data.Inputlist.contains(Data.AthleteData.get(m).getID()))
       {                        
         System.out.println(Data.AthleteData.get(m));
                            }
                        }
        }while(choice);
```

Comment: Either use the contains method to check if it exists or simply use a Set which does not allow for duplicate values

Comment: use a Set and check the return of the method add

Comment: [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) provide methods like [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) or [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) that give you that possibility. But Java provide collection that manage unicity too. **Most of the solution would need to implement `equals` and `hashCode`** since you are using the `id` of the instance stored

Comment: Can contain also work for values Like F001, J123, K12 etc. and what if it is  in uppercase

Comment: yes, unique means unique, as long hashCode and equals are the same, the object will be the same and contains will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a HashSet and see the response of the `add` method as follows:

```
Set<String> someSet = new HashSet<String>();
boolean isUnique = someSet.add("abc");
System.out.println(isUnique); // this will output true as abc does not already exist in the set and add operation was successful            
isUnique = someSet.add("abc");
System.out.println(isUnique); //this will output false as abc already exists in the set and hence cannot be added again
```

But since you are using a Custom Object and not a String, you will need to declare the set as follows:

```
Set<YourClass> someSet = new HashSet<YourClass>();
```

In addition to that you will need to make sure that the equals method in YourObject class is implemented correctly too.
You can refer to these links for more information about equals: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/
and 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/

Comment: You will need to improve that, this is not a `List<String>` like that line suggest `AthleteData.get(j).getID()`. So you need to make it work with custom class

Comment: Fair point. In that case we can go for Set<Whatever Object> and make sure that the equals method of the class is correctly implemented as well.

Comment: That's what I want to find in your answer ;) the need to implements "something" on the class to be able to work correctly in a `Set`

Comment: Vardaan & AxelH Thanks for your input but I still am not getting the output. What I need is I am asking the user to select 5 Players here the user enters the ID say F01 but if he accidentally inputs the same ID again F01 again I want the compiler to detect that and not allow the user to input the same ID again. Where the compiler shows error that the user is already there or does not exist I hope you get where I'm stuck!!

Comment: we could perhaps do this, whenever the user selects an ID you can put it in the HashSet, and see if the add operation returned true. If it is true, it signifies that the entry does not already exists in the HashSet (meaning its unique). so everytime the user selects an id add it to the hash set. If the hash set returns false, it means the ID is already present in it and then you can show "You cannot select the same user again" to the user.

Comment: I'm not adding value to my list. My values are predefined but while selecting from the list if I enter the Same ID again it's not showing error but taking it. If you see my First If statement says at least 5 but when I Select them and input the same ID Twice it compiles and gives me only values that are unique for Instance say I Have Selected F01, F02, F03, F01, F04 it only shows me F01, F02, F03, F04 but does not ask me for the Fifth Player which is the need of my First IF Statement. so I want to apply this check and make sure The user cannot enter the same ID twice

Comment: that is because, when you are doing inputList.add(id) you don't have a check for duplicate value at all. So even if its duplicate or not duplicate your i get incremented. which is why it is showing only f1,f2,f3 and f4. If you replace the input List with a hash set, and do hashset.add(), when it returns true do what you are already doing, if it returns false, system.out.println("error message") and i--;

Comment: My Inputlist .add is the Hash Set String and its all in the same class i.e. private HashSet<String> Inputlist = new HashSet<String>(); public static HashMap<String,Person> info = new HashMap<String,Person>();
 Set<String> keys = info.keySet();
 public static HashMap<String,String> input = new HashMap<String,String>();

Comment: Now where you are checking if(value!=0), put a Boolean vairable to take the output of add. Like, Boolean isUnique = inputList.add(id);. Now check if isUnique is false. if it is false show error message and do i--. I.e if(!isUnique){System.out.println("This is has already been selected"); i--;}

Comment: You are supposed to do i-- not value--

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this.
1.) After taking number you can loop back to check if it exist in the Arraylist.(NOT RECOMMENDED) as it have high runtime complexity.
2.) Simply you can use contains() method of arraylist to check if it is present already.
3) You can use a bitset for number and set it true when ever they are assigned.Later you can compare it with the bool value to check if it set or not. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html for more info on bitset

Comment: FYI : `contains()` loops ;) `List` are not orderer so it probably loops for the beginning to the end. So 1) and 2) have the same "complexity" if 1) stop on the first occurence